# При нажатии b-8 выполняете функцию f8. Функция должна создать массив res8 на основе набора, но добавить только те значения из s8, которых больше 5

Tags: javascript

```
let s8 = new Set([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 9, 23, 45, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 24, 5, 2, 4, 56, 4, 3, 2, 335, 2, 23, 41, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 24, 5, 3, 22, 56]]);

function f8() {
    let res8 = [];
    let out  = document.querySelector('.out-8');
    let arr = Array.from(s8);
       for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
          if(arr[i]>5){
              res8.push(arr[i]);
          }

       }
          return res8  


        }




document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = () => {
    console.log(f8());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
    let s8 = new Set([[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 9, 23, 45, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 24, 5, 2, 4, 56, 4, 3, 2, 335, 2, 23, 41, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 24, 5, 3, 22, 56]]);

    function f8() {
        let res8 = [];
        let arr = Array.from(s8);
        for (let i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++) {
            if(arr[0][i]>5){
                res8.push(arr[0][i]);
            }
        }
        return res8;
    }

    document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = () => {
        let out  = document.querySelector('.out-8');
        out.innerText = f8(s8);
    }
```

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="out-8"></div>
    <button class="b-8">Тык</button>
</div>
```

Comment: А почему бы не просто `return arr[0].filter(n => n > 5)`? А еще есть сильное подозрение, что в вопросе вместо `new Set([[...]])` должно было быть `new Set([...])`, так оно намного осмысленнее. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let s8 = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 7, 9, 5, 7, 8, 9, 23, 45, 5, 2, 4, 5, 3, 24, 5, 2, 4, 56, 4, 3, 2, 335, 2, 23, 41, 3, 4, 1, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 5, 24, 5, 3, 22, 56]);

const f8 = () => {
    let ar8 = [];
   
    for (let item of s8) {
       if(item > 5) ar8.push(item);
    }
    console.log(ar8);
 };

document.querySelector('.b-8').onclick = f8;
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Я думаю, что условие задачи предполагает делать сначала выбору элементов по условию, а потом запись результата в массив